# Can't see syntax error while creating table using SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Not sure where my syntax error is...

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "trackuser": 
syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: 
CREATE TABLE players(firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, category INTEGER, wins INTEGER, losses INTEGER, trackuser INTEGER, FOREIGH KEY(trackuser) REFERENCES users(ID))
```

This is how I created my `users` table

```
CREATE TABLE users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, is_admin INTEGER,username TEXT,password TEXT)
```

Referenced [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) for example

Comment: Change `FOREIGH` to `FOREIGN`

Answer (score 2):

You have got a spelling mistake. You are using `FOREIGH key` instead of `FOREIGN KEY` in your `CREATE TABLE players`-query.

Comment: @Liondancer try to get some sleep ;)